# Combinations - odd num with different start and end

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am having problems with the following combinations problem:

Given a number $1243356$, how many ways are there to form an odd number with different start and end digits?

My approach is to split the problem into two halves:

The first set of numbers excludes $3$ from the last digit. So the choices for last digit are $C(2,1)$. The choices for the first digit are now $C(6,1)$. The rest of the digits can be permuted $5!$ ways. (Not forgetting there are duplicate $3$'s, we must divide by $2!$)

The second set of numbers fixes $3$ as the last digit. So there is one choice for the last digit. The choices for the first digit are now $C(5,1)$. The rest of the digits can also be permuted $5!$ ways.

Hence, total number of combinations $$=\frac{C(2,1) \cdot C(6,1) \cdot 5!}{2!} + C(5,1) \cdot 5! = \frac{12 \cdot 120}{2!} + 5 \cdot 120 = 1300$$

However my solution is incorrect based on the answer key. The correct answer is supposedly 1320. Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: "different start and end digits"? Can you give two combinations that are considered identical for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasonning is correct, but not the computation : $6! = (C(2,1)C(6,1)\times 5!)/2! = 720$ and $5 \times 120 = 600$.

Note that for the first part, you can fix the last digit ($C(2,1)=2$ possibilities). Then you do not have to treat the first digit separately since there is no special constraint on it. So there is $6!/2!$ possibilities for the $6$ first digits, and finally $2\times 6!/2=6!$ possibilities for the first part.